# Difference between jQuery 3.0 and earlier versions with handling of '.load()'?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I have a relatively simple 'lightbox.js' file that I've used for image galleries on a few websites since about 2013. From the beginning it has run with jQuery 1.8.3, but I'm updating one of the sites and thought I should update the jQ to 3.4.0. But my script doesn't work with jQuery 3.4.0 (or 3.4.1).

The gallery, working with jQuery 1.8.3, may be seen at: http://mull-bed-and-breakfast.co.uk/gallerytn

I now find that with jQuery 3.4.0 'lightbox.js' no longer works as intended. Instead I get the typical 'default' action from clicking on an image that has a link to a larger version - the image is shown centre-screen with a black background, but no frame and no controls. I conclude that jQuery 3.4.0 isn't getting to the end of the function, so doesn't read the 'return false'.

I've tried putting 'event.prevent.Default()' as the first line of the lightbox 'click' function. Now the process stops after creating the 80% overlay but before displaying the image. I suspect that there's something else in my original script that jQ 3.4.0 doesn't like.

I think I've tracked this down to the lines:

```
    $('<img />')
        .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
        .load(function() {
            positionLightboxImage();
        })
        .appendTo('#lightbox');
```

which is intended to append the 'image' element and position it centrally (and works in jQ 1.8.3)

From the jQuery documentation re .load(): "Note: Prior to jQuery 3.0, the event handling suite also had a method named .load(). Older versions of jQuery determined which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it."

I'm thinking that my use of '.load()' here is no longer supported in jQuery 3.4.0, but I've so far not worked out how else to call the 'positionLightboxImage' function at this point in the script. (the function is defined in my script).

How should this be done in jQ 3.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `on('load', handler)`

```
$('<img />')
        .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
        .on('load', positionLightboxImage)
        .appendTo('#lightbox');
```

Within `positionLightboxImage()` function ...  `this` will be the specific image element

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you. Easier than I'd expected, I hadn't fully understood the syntax around ".on('load')", but I'll look again with better understanding.